# phpBB3 disabling Friends & Foes

Tags: phpbb3

I am using [phpBB3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS7hD.jpg) Version 3.0.12. I do not want that the users can add each other as friends. Therefore I went to

SYSTEM-> User Control Panel -> Disabled Friends & Foes

[image]

I have refreshed my template and cleared the cache, but when I log in as a user I still can see the **Private Message** button

[image]

However, when one clicks on it the following error appears:

[image]

How can I remove this **PM** icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no link between «Friends and Foes» and «Private Message». You don't have this message because FF feature is disabled.

On your board, there is a bug on Private Message click, because Private Message feature is disabled.

If you want to remove «Private Message» feature (and link buttons), it will be easier (and a better practice) to go to :

**General > Board Configuration > Board Features**

Check No on «Private Messaging» feature.

[image: Screenshot : Private messaging : No]

You could optionnaly return on System > Module Managment > User Control Panel to enable Private Message. «PM links» still won't appears.

I think that the Friends and Foes feature is well disabled. As you can see in [memberlist_view.html file](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/release-3.0.12/phpBB/styles/prosilver/template/memberlist_view.html) (line 26) «Friends and Foes» buttons only appears when `S_ZEBRA` is true. S_ZEBRA is true when user is registered and module FF is on.